# SQLAlchemy column type comparison

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm doing a lot of database introspections across different database types and I would like to be able to compare two column types. For example, a field defined as `Boolean` type using the `declarative_base()` is then converted to a specific `TINYINT` for the **MySQL** dialact, so a check like this:

```
model_a.__table__.columns['col'].type == model_b.__table__.columns['col'].type
```

doesn't work, and neither this one:

```
(type_a == type_b) or issubclass(type_b, type_a)
```

How can I compare two columns for data type "affinity"? (By inspecting the code I saw that column types have a `Comparator` class attached but I'm not sure if it can be of any help and how to use it)
Is also possible to force a column type in the **SQLAlchemy** configuration (by avoiding dialect-specific convertion)?

Answer (score 5):

(Answering an old question because I've been looking into exactly this).

The quickest solution is to compare the str() of the types:

`assert str(type_a) == (type_b)`

That'll work for simple types, but if you have any `Variant` types or wrappers (for example, `MutableDict` wrapping Postgres `JSON`) then you'll have to handle a special case.

Comment: conversion to str may not represent type characteristics, e.g. in sqlalchemy 1.4.44 ``str(column.type)`` would return ``NUMBER`` and ``repr(column.type)`` would return ``NUMBER(precision=9, scale=0, asdecimal=False)``

Answer (score 2):

For example to check if a type is a BLOB. Use this code:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
some code..
if type(column.type) is db.types.BLOB:
    something..
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose to compare the `repr()` of the type of the column.

```
repr(model_a.tables[table_name].columns[column_name].type) == \
repr(model_b.tables[table_name].columns[column_name].type)
```

Note that conversion to string of the column type may not represent type detailed characteristics, e.g. in sqlalchemy 1.4.44 `str(column.type)` would return `NUMBER` and `repr(column.type)` would return `NUMBER(precision=9, scale=0, asdecimal=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread while searching for the same answer in 2019--here's what's worked for me, if anyone else comes along.

To check for strict type equality for SQLAlchemy types on a Column `'col'` present in tables `model_a` and `model_b` use:

```
isinstance(model_a.columns['col'].type, type(model_b.columns['col'].type)) and
isinstance(model_b.columns['col'].type, type(model_a.columns['col'].type))
```

You'll need both `isinstance` clauses (i.e., "Is A a B?" *and* "Is B an A?") to reject situations where either table has subclassed column types rather than identical types.

However, if your types don't need to be strictly equal and subclasses are acceptable, you can remove one or the other of the `isinstance` clauses.

Comment: Good approach but I miss the possibility of detecting the difference of a column with type ``NUMBER(9,0)`` and another column with type ``NUMBER(6,2)``

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would apply to your specific use case, but you can compare column types based on their respective Python type using `column.type.python_type`.

Example ORM Model

```
class Example(Base)
    exCol1 = Column(String)
    exCol2 = Column(String)
    exCol3 = Column(Integer)
```

Comparing column types:

```
In [1]: Example.__table__.columns['exCol1'].type.python_type == Example.__table__.columns['exCol2'].type.python_type
Out[1]: True
In [2]: Example.__table__.columns['exCol1'].type.python_type == Example.__table__.columns['exCol3'].type.python_type
Out[2]: False
```